# max of a max of a function for subset of ids in single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, aggregate-functions, aggregation

How do I make the following code into a single query :

Nodes : id,value

i.e. get back Max of the Max of function applied for subset of nodes against the whole table

this is pseudo code.
The DB is postgresql

```
#select the nodes, filtered by some criteria
Nodes = select id,value from nodes where ....

#for every node.value find the max of fun() applied to the whole table, collect it
FOR n IN Nodes :
  Maxes.append( 
     select s.id, MAX(fun(n.value, s.value)) 
     from nodes s 
     where s.id != n.id
  )

#find the Max-score&Id of the collected Max scores
ID,score = MAX(Maxes)
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would help.

Comment: What language is that?  It doesn't look like SQL to me.

Answer (score 0):

in sql , you just call max() , it's an aggregation function and runs against the whole data set you feed it, so your query would be as simple as:

```
select max(fun(n1.value, n2.value))
from nodes n1
join nodes n2
 on n1.id <> n2.id 
where ....
```

of course you need to define and make  fun() function in advance in your postgresl

Comment: thanks .. the fun() returns score not a vector. And the fun() depends on two vectors. Every selected-node has its own max-score and from those max-scores I have to pick the max .. in a sense its loop within a loop

Comment: isnt this joining going to do the MAX only on the "cross".. it has to apply the fun() to the whole table once for every selected-node  ..

Comment: @sten , well then remove the where clause . anyways , with this little information provided in the question , this seems answer the question , otherwise you have to provide sample data and desired output and a complete explaianation